# build json array in php dynamically

Tags: php, json

I can create simple json objects like this:

```
$d = array('item' => "$name" ,'rate' => "$rating");
```

But what if I want to build an array of items and do it dynamically since I am building it from a db query?

Update:

Let me be more specific I know I have to do:

```
$jsonCode = json_encode($d);
```

which will create a json object with an item and rate field. But I want multiple json objects in a json array when i encode it.

What I want json wise is something like this:

```
[{"item":"toy","rating":"baz" },{"item":"bike","rating":"2.3" }, {"item":"juice","rating":"1.3" }]
```

Comment: That is not JSON. That is a PHP array.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's just a PHP array.

Comment: That's not JSON, it is just a PHP array. :)

Comment: All together, with feeling!

Comment: Wanting **multiple json objects in a json array/object** sounds to me like wanting **multiple arrays in an array**. Just saying though. Unless you want to store json strings in an array. Not really sure though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> But I want multiple json objects in a json array when i encode it.

Then create an **array of arrays** and pass it to `json_encode`. The [documentation about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) explains how to add elements to an array, in the section *Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax*.

Associative arrays, like the one you already have, will be encoded as objects, "normal" arrays (arrays with consecutive numerical keys) will be encoded as arrays.

Example:

```
$d = array();

// This appends a new element to $d, in this case the value is another array
$d[] = array('item' => "$name" ,'rate' => "$rating");

$json = json_encode($d);
```

Comment: a rare oasis where php is actually idiomatic and easy, rather than imperative and idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 9):

This will create a multi-dimensional array from your database query, and then encode it as JSON.

```
$d = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
  $d[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($d);
```

Each `$row` will be an associative array of the data returned from the database. Assigning it to `$d[]` adds it as an indexed element of that container array.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your array as you just have done but then pass the array through `json_encode`?

If you want a multi-dimensional array, try

```
$array[] = array("key1" => value1, "key2" => value2);
```

Comment: Reading between the lines, his real problem is he doesn't know how to create multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Please read when he updated, he didn't put that he didn't know how to do that or what he exactly wanted when I posted the comment

Comment: Even at the beginning, it seemed obvious he didn't know how to create an array dynamically. He wrote _what if I want to build an array of items and do it dynamically_.

Comment: Edited it, should be abit better

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a php array dynamically as you want then covert it into a json array as below.

```
$json_array = json_encode($array);
```

Keep in mind that what you have provided is not a json array

Comment: I just updated my original questions as I was not specific enough