# Dialog Didn't show and no response from php

Tags: php, android

I try to make an insert to MySQL Database, it works but alert dialog didn't shown and i don't got any response from my php, also i got error, i don't know what is it cause i'm new on android

Here is the complete code:

```
public class TransaksiBaru extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText et_trans, et_total, et_anggota;
Button tambah;
String transaksi, total, anggota;
String url_trans = "http://10.0.2.2/test/new.php";
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaksi_baru);

    et_trans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_transaksi);
    et_total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_total);
    et_anggota = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
    tambah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tambah);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TransaksiBaru.this);

    tambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            transaksi = et_trans.getText().toString();
            total = et_total.getText().toString();
            anggota = et_anggota.getText().toString();
            if (transaksi.equals("") || total.equals("") || anggota.equals("")) {
                builder.setMessage("Data Belum Lengkap....");
                displayAlert("input_error");
            } else {
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_trans,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                                    builder.setMessage(message);
                                    displayAlert(code);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("transaksi", transaksi);
                        params.put("nilai", total);
                        params.put("id_anggota1", anggota);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                AppController.getInstance(TransaksiBaru.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void displayAlert(final String str) {
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (str.equals("input_error")) {

            }
            else if (str.equals("input_sukses"))
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

And here is the php code :

```
include "init.php";

$transaksi  = $_POST['transaksi'];
$nilai = $_POST['nilai'];
$id_anggota1 = $_POST['id_anggota1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO transaksi (id_transaksi,transaksi,total,id_anggota) VALUES('','".$transaksi."','".$nilai."','".$id_anggota1."')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();
$code = "input_sukses";
$message = "Data Berhasil Ditambahkan....";
array_push($response, array("code"=>$code,"message" => $message));
echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Alert dialog works for input_error, but didn't works for input_sukses

Also i got this error :

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><h3>Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
W/System.err:     at com.rzproject.koperasi.TransaksiBaru$1$1.onResponse(TransaksiBaru.java:67)
W/System.err:     at com.rzproject.koperasi.TransaksiBaru$1$1.onResponse(TransaksiBaru.java:62)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Judging from the error u posted the response u r getting from php is not of JSONArray format. What is the response u r expecting from the php code ?? Post that as well

Comment: @ik024 editted, please check

Comment: PHP is not my forte, but I think the php code u posted might have error creating a correct json array object. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332163/build-json-array-in-php-dynamically

Comment: @ik024 thanks, hope it works

Comment: Np. Let me know if it works.